# Generating 5 digit alphanumeric code with predifined characters in sequence

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier, base-conversion

I would like to generate a membership number consisting of alphanumeric characters, removing `i` `o` and `l` to save confusion when typing. to be done in php (also using Laravel 5.7 if that matters - but i feel this is a php question)

If simply using 0-9 the membership number would start at 00001 for the 1st one and the 11th person would have 00011. I would like to use alphanumeric characters from 0-9 + a-z (removing said letters)

0-9 (total 10 characters), abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz (total 23 characters) - this giving a total of 33 characters in each count cycle (0-10+a-Z). instead of just 10 (0-10)

So the first membership number would still be 00001 where as the 12th would now be 0000a, 14th 0000c and 34th would be 0001a.

To summarize i need a way of defining the characters for counting in a way that can be generated based on the id of a user.

I hope I have explained this well enough.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Single case for characters, it is to simplify a code that can be written or printed on items on very small labels. The idea being they can be short codes that are easy to typed into a form. The reason i would like to use aphpa numeric is the at 5 characters using numbers, we can only go up to 99,999, where using 33 characters for each of the 5 digits, we can get 39,135,393. Then at a later stage if we need more, we can simply ad a 6th on the end and so forth

Comment: Wait, wait, the 10th id should be `0000a`.  You wouldn't want to use `00010` before `0000a` -- for a couple of reasons.  1. You would lose `sort()`-ability and 2. You go from "one-character" to "two-character" then back to "one-character" logic.

Comment: Yes, i really need to set my own count, instead of 0-9 it needs to be 0-9 + a-z (although we plan to change the order of the characters - but that isn't important right now)

Comment: In a base 33 numbers, 34th would be 00011.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that these are the only characters you want to use:

```
0123456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz
```

You can use `base_convert()` and `strtr()` to translate specific characters of the result to the characters you want.

```
function mybase33($number) {
    return str_pad(strtr(base_convert($number, 10, 33), [
        'i' => 'j',
        'j' => 'k',
        'k' => 'm',
        'l' => 'n',
        'm' => 'p',
        'n' => 'q',
        'o' => 'r',
        'p' => 's',
        'q' => 't',
        'r' => 'u',
        's' => 'v',
        't' => 'w',
        'u' => 'x',
        'v' => 'y',
        'w' => 'z',
    ]), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo "9 is ".mybase33(9)."\n";
echo "10 is ".mybase33(10)."\n";
echo "12 is ".mybase33(12)."\n";
echo "14 is ".mybase33(14)."\n";
echo "32 is ".mybase33(32)."\n";
echo "33 is ".mybase33(33)."\n";
echo "34 is ".mybase33(34)."\n";
```

Output:

```
9 is 00009
10 is 0000a
12 is 0000c
14 is 0000e
32 is 0000z
33 is 00010
34 is 00011
```

https://3v4l.org/8YtaR

**Explanation**

The output of `base_convert()` uses these characters:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

The `strtr()` translates specific characters of that output to:

```
0123456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: although i don't fully understand how that works, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: How would i make that a minimum of 5 characters? also if we run out of 5 digit codes, how do we make it 6? then 7 and 8 in the future?

Comment: use `str_pad()`

Comment: it already works up and up, i just don't understand the array part 'i' => 'j',

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, `strtr()` takes care of that.

Comment: @The-WebGuy Added explanation.

Comment: This answer is mega classy! one-up.  @The-WebGuy You're going to accept this one, right?