# php base_convert works fine locally, but not on ubuntu 18 LTS server (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-5.7

Hell internet world

I bring another weird and wonderful question to you today.

See the code blow, locally (using Laravel's inbuilt php serve functionality, this outputs the following:

**Which is the desired result**

```
[2019-01-31 14:33:07] local.DEBUG: >>: q  
[2019-01-31 14:33:07] local.DEBUG: --: q  
[2019-01-31 14:33:07] local.DEBUG: ##: 0000q
```

However, the same files, uploaded to an AWS t2.micro server running Ubuntu 18 LTS - i receive the following:

**not desired**

```
[2019-01-31 14:22:47] local.DEBUG: >>: 14  
[2019-01-31 14:22:47] local.DEBUG: --: 14  
[2019-01-31 14:22:47] local.DEBUG: ##: 00014
```

Here is the code snippet to generate an alpha numeric membership number:

[Thanks to this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021386/generating-5-digit-alphanumeric-code-with-predifined-characters-in-sequence)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\RegisterFormRequest;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use JWTAuth;
use PragmaRX\Countries\Package\Countries;
use App\Mail\Welcome;
use App\cart_storage;

use Log;

class AuthController extends Controller
{


    private function generateVerification($name, $title) {
        return md5( $name.substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"), 0, 9).$title );
    }
    private function mybase33($number) {
        return strtr(base_convert($number, 10, 33), [
            'i' => 'j',
            'j' => 'k',
            'k' => 'm',
            'l' => 'n',
            'm' => 'p',
            'n' => 'q',
            'o' => 'r',
            'p' => 's',
            'q' => 't',
            'r' => 'u',
            's' => 'v',
            't' => 'w',
            'u' => 'x',
            'v' => 'y',
            'w' => 'z',
        ]);
    }
    public function registerItem(request $request){

        $id = (int)Auth::user()->id;
        $memberCodeShort = $this->mybase33($id);
        $membershipNumber = str_pad($memberCodeShort, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        Log::debug('>>: '.$this->mybase33($id));
        //$user->membership_number = $this->generateMembershipNumber($id);

        Log::debug('--: '.$memberCodeShort);
        Log::debug('##: '.$membershipNumber);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what to look at, i'm completely lost. But my gut is telling me there is likely to be something missing or not setup on the server correctly

Comment: Given that it's based on `$id`, I'd guess you've got different IDs on local versus production. Log the value of `$id`.

Comment: oh my god, that makes so much sense - i hadn't considered that since i migrated the database - let me go check that out

Comment: yes that was exactly it, the user had been removed and assigned a new ID. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help, haha!

Comment: you think you have tried everything, then when you finally know the problem, it's glaringly obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to formalize things from the comments:

Your user ID is different on production.